# Using Accord.Net's Naive Bayes, how do I store training?

Tags: asp.net, bayesian, accord.net

Using Accord.Net's Naive Bayes, how do I store learning so I don't have to train the classifier again?

I have a very large data set and I don't want to have to run the whole thing again when I spin up a new instance or the server goes down.

This trains:
`double error = bayes.Estimate(inputs, outputs);`

This tests:
`int answer = bayes.Compute(new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 });`

I was hoping there was a model created by .Estimate() that I could store somewhere and use to initialise the bayes quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any model in the Accord.NET framework can be saved using standard .NET serialization. Your '''bayes''' variable can be saved using:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream fs = new FileStream("bayes.bin", FileMode.Create);
formatter.Serialize(fs, bayes);
```

and loaded back using

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream fs = new FileStream("bayes.bin", FileMode.Read);
var bayes = (NaiveBayes)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
```

Comment: Update: all models can now be saved using the Serializer class: http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_IO_Serializer.htm